# Windows 10 client does not get a temporary CAL form Win 2k3 TS

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-10, windows-terminal-services

### tl;dr;

Windows 10 client is not getting issued a temporary CAL to connect to a Win2k3 TS.

### Details

- Win2k3 Terminal Server, Per Device CAL mode
- No available CAL's atm, I expect it to issue a temporary CAL
- Error text on trying to connect

> The remote session was disconnected because there are no Remote Desktop client access licenses available for this computer.  Please contact the server administrator.

### What I've tried

- Deleted the `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\MSLicensing` key in client registry and ran mstsc again as admin
- Connected to TS using `mstsc /admin` switch.  This works fine.
- Connected with a Windows 7 computer. Temp license issued.
- Event log on the TS has entries for event 1004 with this text

> The terminal server cannot issue a client license.  It was unable to issue the license due to a changed (mismatched) client license, insufficient memory, or an internal error. Further details for this problem may have been reported at the client's computer.

- Event log on the client has no entries that I could find